# Incompatible version requirements when install package through pip

Tags: pip, conda, python-packaging

I have a conda environment. I want to install [DeepSpeech](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in it. When I install it through pip I get an error, but the deepspeech package still gets installed.

```
ERROR: tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3", but you'll have scipy 1.5.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0, but you'll have tensorboard 2.2.1 which is incompatible.
```

What does this mean? I know I had tensorflow installed before, does this mean it got reinstalled, but it still has previous dependencies or were other libraries changed and the previous tensorflow is now incompatible.

The output of `pip3 check`

```
tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3", but you have scipy 1.5.0.
tensorflow 2.1.0 has requirement tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0, but you have tensorboard 2.2.1.
pathos 0.2.7 has requirement dill>=0.3.3, but you have dill 0.2.9.
multiprocess 0.70.11.1 has requirement dill>=0.3.3, but you have dill 0.2.9.
```

Comment: Which version of _pip_ are you using? What is the output of `python -m pip check`?

Comment: Looks like the installation process for that library is not that straightforward. The official way to get support for this seems to be to reach to their "discourse" forums: https://discourse.mozilla.org/search?q=install%20pip%20category%3A247

Comment: Yes, it is not straight-forward at all. Interesting enough I now installed deepspeech in a completely new environment and tensorflow or scipy do not even get installed?

Comment: Conda doesn't alias `pip` to `pip3`, so `pip3` is definitely pointing to a system- or user-level Python install. If you must resort to PyPI in a Conda env, you need to use simply `pip install` with the environment activated.

Comment: Just do not use `pip` or `pip3` at all. Please we have to stop with this once and for all. You have to call `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip check` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
pip uninstall scipy
pip uninstall tensorboard 
pip install --ignore-installed tensorflow==2.1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this. The scipy is now 1.4.1. and tensorboard 2.1.1. With this we can still not say whether tensorflow was reinstalled in the process or whether only the dependent libraries were changed.

Comment: All reinstalled, scipy on tensorflow requieres, tensorboar on tensorflow requires, and tensorflow on 2.1.0

Comment: With your commands yes. But I don't know what happened in the deepspeach installation. Possibly only the dependent libraries were changed.

Comment: That cause install can upgrade, not downgrade versions
Can u set answer as solution?